# .RDS files and GPL license in R

Tags: gpl, license-compatibility

We are building an application that uses machine learning to predict certain parameters and use them in an optimization algorithm afterwards.

We are not building the front-end in R neither the back-end and our only R component is the feature engineering, training, serialization and prediction scripts that generate a couple of .RDS files and expose them via REST-API using AWS sagemaker endpoints.

1. The feature engineering is done with dplyr (MIT license), lubridate
   (GPL2/3) and forecastML (MIT license).
2. The training is done using
       keras with tensorflow backend (Apache license), glmnet (GPL2/3) and
       xgboost (Apache License).
3. Prediction is done with the same libraries and with MLflow (MIT license) which exposes this model to sagemaker
4. Serialization is done of course with base R.

If my end-user is an external company that is going to take the results of the optimization (which are consequently feed with the machine learning predictions) do I have a problem in terms of licensing?

At the end the end-user does not receive any code it only receives the predictions via an API.

Best Regards

Comment: Data generated with a programme are not subject to the license of the programme used to generate it. You may do with your work whatever you do and provide it on your terms, irrespective of the terms of your tools. Independent of that, not affecting your data: some tools require a special license if you use them commercially; that seems not be the case for you.